# How to enable serial communication on Pi 4 using BookWorm OS?

Tags: pi-4, bluetooth, serial, uart, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

Raspberry Pi 4 and Latest Raspbian Bookworm OS.

I want to have Pi 4 communicate over serial connection using GPIO14 (BCM) and GPIO15 (BCM) or UART TX and UART RX.

I have followed the same setups that I have done for my previous Pis (2 and 3) as follows to enable serial communication.

- executed `sudo raspi-config` to enable serial interface to YES.
- installed wiringpi.
- set GPIO14 and GPIO15 to `ALT0`.
- Added `enable_uart=1` and also disabled bluetooth `dtoverylay=disable-bt` in `/boot/config.txt`.
- Disabled ttyAMA0 by `sudo systemctl mask serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service`
- Reboot Pi.

These steps works and worked on my previous versions of pi but not on Pi 4.

No data is transmitted, but after much testing I noticed that whenever I re-enable bluetooth by commenting out `dtoverlay=disable-bt` in `/boot/config.txt` Pi 4 transmits outgoing data but DOES NOT READ the incoming serial data.

There is obviously some differences in Pi 4 and the previous versons of Pis. I can't seem to find any solutions that work so far.

Any hints or clues?

Comment: You have posted no diagnostics and are using unusual (and unnecessary) commands. If you just tried the standard commands it should work. Frankly I fail to understand WHY so many people want to disable Bluetooth. The Pi4 has 5 usable UART.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Rasperry Pi OS from late 2023, with the Bookworm kernel, `config.txt` should be in
`/boot/firmware`,
ie `/boot/firmware/config.txt`